# How to keep SOLR running on remote server

Tags: linux, solr, amazon-ec2

I have a site that uses a solr search engine, but I've only been able to use it while I'm ssh'ed into the server (Amazon EC2) and run the java -jar start.jar. As soon as I log out of the ssh session, it stops running and nothing is searchable anymore. How can I keep this running even when I'm not accessing the server?

If this needs any more clarification, just comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use

```
nohup java -jar start.jar &
```

to achieve what you want.

Comment: I use `pkill -f "start.jar"` for that. Not entirely true, I add an "ID" in the command, which I use for identifying the process robustly, such as `nohup java -Dsolr -jar start.jar &` for starting and `pkill -f Dsolr` for stopping. If it doesn't shut down after some seconds, I call `pkill -9 -f Dsolr`

Answer (score 0):

Either convince it to run in daemon mode, or start it with something like setsid to disassociate it from your login session ID, so that it won't be terminated when your login session is.